# Is there any SOAP object available to pull journey information from marketing cloud?

Tags: c#, .net, soap, exacttarget, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am trying to download the journey information from marketing cloud and understand how it's related to a _Job dataview. Is there any Object that directly pulls all journey related information using SOAP API calls?

I have downloaded the _Journey dataview by querying it to a data extension, but I can not figure out how it's related to a _Job dataview. How can I connect the Journey information to the _Job dataview?
Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot go directly between _Journey and _Job. May you can try relating _Sent DataView to _JourneyActivity

According to the documentation

> JourneyActivityObjectID corresponds to TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
>   in the _Sent, _Open, _Click, and _Bounce, data views

These are some links to doc for further information: [_JobActivity Data View doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_journey_activity.htm&type=5)
[_Sent Data View doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sent.htm&type=5)

I hope this may helps you.